# I need a Regular Expression allowing user to input numbers, plus, minus and parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regular Expression allowing user to input numbers, plus, minus and parentheses.

User can only input:

- At most one open parenthesis '('.
- At most one close parenthesis ')'.
- At most one plus '+'
- As many minus '-' but not after each other.
- Exactly 11 numbers.

Here are valid inputs:

```
(0)+12-3-4-56-7890
+)0(12345-678-90
+01234567890
+(01234567890)
01234567890
-01-234+5678-90
(01234567890)
)01234567890(
```

And following are not valid:

```
0123456--7890
0((1234567890
01234567890))
++01234567890
123456
++123456789
```

I'm using C# for programming and if it helps order of open and close parentheses can become mandatory too. so `)01234567890(` will not be valid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex passes your examples, but might not be exactly what you're looking for. It should point you in the right direction.

```
^(?!.*-{2,})(?!(?:.*\)){2,})(?!(?:.*\(){2,})(?!\+{2,})(?:\D*\d\D*){11}$
```

- (?!.*-{2,}) Cannot contain two or more hyphens.
- (?!(?:.*)){2,}) Cannot contain two or more closing parentheses.
- (?!(?:.*(){2,}) Cannot contain two or more opening parentheses.
- (?!+{2,}) Cannot start with more than two addition symbols.
- (?:\D*\d\D*){11} Must contain 11 instances of a numeric character surrounded by anything.

However, this is very confusing and fairly inefficient. I bet the regex could be rewritten to be much quicker, but won't be much easier to understand.

I suggest that you follow MisterJack's suggestion instead of pursue a regex. It'll be easier to maintain.

**EDIT**

---

```
^(?!.*--)(?!.*(\(|\)|\+).*\1)(?:\D*\d\D*){11}$
```

I've consolidated the parentheses and plus symbol rules into one negative lookahead using a backreference. This also restricts the number of parens and pluses to just one of each. I couldn't get it to restrict to just a certain set of characters, but you might be able to do that in a second pass with another regex.

- ^ Match from beginning of the string
- (?!.*--) Do not allow consecutive hyphens
- (?!.* ((|)|+).*\1) Do not allow two or more instances of () or +
- (?:\D*\d\D*){11} Must contain 11 digits, allow non-digit characters before and after, such as hyphen.
- $ Match to end of string

I tried a negative and positive lookahead to restrict the characters, but couldn't get it to work right. I also tried to replace \D with [()+-] but that didn't work either. Maybe someone else will add a comment to show how to restrict the characters. I'd sure love to see how someone else does it in this regex.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it is almost there and happy that at least I get one close answer. plus and parenthesis cannot repeat more than once, is it possible to combine them in one single rule?

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean that only one plus, one open parenthesis, and one close parenthesis can exist in the string? I might've been confused by "at most one open plus".
I'll see what I can do about consolidating the rules a bit.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. I updated the question to clear it out. And plus can be anywhere in the code just like '(' and ')'

Comment: Does it matter if other characters are entered? Or should it be limited to just ()+- and numbers?

Comment: great job, you are right, only allowed characters are '(' , ')', '+' , '-' and numbers. your expression works great, except it allows entering two plus sign that is not allowed.

I guess I need to update the 4th part to (?!(?:.*\+){2,})

Comment: I updated my answer to consolidate and correct the symbol restriction to allow only one of each paren and addition symbol. I couldn't get it to restrict to a subset of characters. Sorry. :(

Comment: I want to change the expression as i want with numbers and plus minus sign no brackets. The following example should pass by such expression. eg:

13213,
13131-46321,
23131-131,
3123123+13213,
31231+12323

I need expression for this input? @NickVanderPayle

Comment: @NomiAli Please ask in a new question. If I can't get around to answering it, I'm sure someone else would love the opportunity to help. :)

Comment: @NickVanderPyle I can't question anymore. I'm block on stackoverflo, thats why i try to ask in comments area. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that a regular expression isn't your best bet, because it could become too much complicated and it can easily be broken.

What I suggest you is to try to parse your input, i.e. to count how many numbers, minuses, plus and parenthesis the user entered, and if they appear in the right order. An easy way to do this could be to loop over the characters that compose the string and check if the current char:

- is a number (and we keep count of how many numbers we found)
- is a minus (and the previous char isn't a minus)
- is a plus (and it is the first one)
- is a parenthesis (it's the first open parenthesis **or** it's a closed one and we already found the open parenthesis)

This could do the trick.

Comment: From your answer and your previous answers I understand that Regular Expression is not your area of expertise. I don't understand why you down voted my question!

Please check answer from @NickVanderPyle